# Python re.sub() with dots

Tags: python, regex

I would like to put a space before and after a dot in text but only if its not a part of a date.

So far I have this, and I figured out I have to do something with `\D\`. but it gives back the letter before the dot not only the dot:

```
string = re.sub("\.", " . ", string)
```

For example:

Input text:

```
1992.01.04 is my birthday.
```

Required output:

```
1992.01.04 is my birthday .
```

There is a space before the end of string dot.

Other question is the same with colon and time,

Input text:

```
The time is 11:48, reported by: Tom.
```

Required output:

```
The time is 11:48, reported by : Tom.
```

There is a space after text `'reported by'` before the colon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex which does a negative look ahead and negative look behind to check if dot/colon is surrounded by digits and replace it with ' \1 '

```
(?<!\d\d)([.:])(?!\d+)
```

Demo, https://regex101.com/r/hr6slz/4

This regex works for both colon and dot and as you can replace it by ' \1 '

Comment: Thanks, it is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: I have updated my answer and with provided same regex you can apply it for dot as well as colon. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You need _ positive lookbehind assertion._ (or negative, with `\d`). Look into https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html for details.

```
re.sub("(?<=\D)\.(\D?)", " . ", '1992.01.04 is my birthday.')
```